# Simulate dynamic playback head with AudioKit (scratching / tunrtablism)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-audio, audiokit

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate the scratching of a record player with AudioKit.
So basically to have an input value (e.g. position of the finger on screen) as input for the index of the playback of an audio-file. I am not sure if Audio Kit is even possible of doing something like that. If not how would I program something like this for iOS? Any other frameworks/libraries? Will I need to write c++?

Thank you,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AKPhaseLockedVocoder. Its pretty cool, does exactly that.

Comment: Thnx Aurelius! Although that is indeed pretty cool, and works really well., I was looking for a regular way to read into a sample file without having pitch and time separated. So when I would swipe faster the pitch would go up as opposed to go down. Is there another class in AK that does this? A phased sample reader with a phase input as index? Thank you

Comment: Maybe try AKTimePitch for that?